# simple function not returning proper column number in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I edit column K, the logfile says columnNum= 1, when it should be 11.  Am I perhaps using the logging function wrong?  Or not testing it right somehow?  What could be the problem?  Thank you in advance.

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  var columnNum = r.getColumn();

    var msg = 'columnNum= ' + columnNum;
  Logger.log (msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Logger only records values when the script is run from within the Script Manager. This is conflicting with the way that onEdit functions operate. Replace Logger.log (msg); with Browser.msgBox(msg); and see if the output is still incorrect.

If you need to store the values generated from msg you may like to print the values to a separate sheet.

Comment: I was in fact running it from within script manager.  It turns out I needed to close and reopen the browser window.  That fixed it.  I have a different problem now, I'll start a new post.  Thanks for the input!